# How to install a database dump via Shell Script?

Tags: shell-script, mysql, remote

I have a Mysql database dump. I want to install it with Hudson via a Shell Script to an external Linux machine.

How can you take a Mysql script and run it inside a database on other machine? I know I can transfer files with sftp and use ssh when accessing another machines manually, but how to automate this all to a simple Shell Script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ mysql -p$pass -u$user -h$otherhost $db < dumpfile
```

This assumes `dumpfile` is text from `mysqldump`, containing raw SQL statements.

It is important that there be no space between `-p` and the password. (I assume you want automatic login.) If the password does not immediately follow the `-p`, `mysql` interprets the option as meaning it should ask interactively for the password, and treats the separate password argument as the DB name.

For this to work, `$user` must have permission to log in, drop a table, create a table, and insert rows into that table, all as a remote user. MySQL keeps separate remote and local permissions for users, so this is an easy trap to fall into. Because allowing a remote user this much power is a security risk, you may want to use SSL (`--ssl*` options) with `mysql`. Otherwise, I don't know that I would allow a remote user to do such things.

Comment: +1: That serves quite well what I am trying to do. Thanks!